# How to populate input only after applying some filters in kibana dadhboard

Tags: filter, conditional-statements, kibana, interactive

In my dashboard, I am analyzing the cost of different Azure subscription. My requirement is to populate a range slider only when the filter scoping specific type of resource cost.

i.e.; range slider will be visible only after adding a filter Microsoft.Compute.

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'll guess you need to create a custom plugin or (maybe) create an "scripted field".

Comment: Hi Yannick, thanks for comment. I'm new to kibana. Can give me some websites or links, where I can find related information? About scripted field or custom plugin.

Comment: Hey hemanth, just a couple of weeks ago, i followed this "guide": https://medium.com/query-ai/how-to-set-up-the-kibana-plugin-development-environment-f64ad8aceb80